# why image is not loading to the view page in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am doing a project and I want to get the image from table and display it in a particular division, when I check the check the code using breakpoints ,noticed that the image is not loading to the view page

view page

```
<div class="board_cont">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="content_headings">Board of Directors</h3>
        @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (j <= 2)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4 director-board-head">
                <div class="board-head-top">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].Designation)</div>
                <div class="border-head-content">
                    <div class="image_div" style="background:@Url.Content("~/BoardImages/" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].PhotoUrl))"></div>
                    <p class="boad_name" style="padding-top:10px;text-align:center"><b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].Name)</b></p>
                    <p class="boad_number" style="padding-top:3px;text-align:center" align=center>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].Phone)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
           }
       }
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
    public ActionResult Board()
    {
        var selectResult = db.Boards.ToList();
        return View(selectResult);
    }
```

Iam getting value from table and in the view page all the details except image is not retrieving from table and no error generating. How come that happends, it seems the code to be correct. Can anyone please help me to find a solution for my problem ??

Comment: Try removing `Html.DisplayFor` on `Url.Content` inside div tag and use raw path insertion instead.

Comment: Inspect the html your generating - what is the value of the `style` attribute?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke   It shows a strike over the style attribute

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto how can I give raw path? it only display one image at a time know ?

Comment: are you displaying image by image path?

Comment: No, I need to get it from the folder saved in the application, want to get each image in the for loop

Comment: what does m => m[j].PhotoUrl returns?

Comment: for getting each image saved under the name photoUrl in table

Comment: May you can rewrite your question to make us understand you

Comment: @user256 Check what this expression  "~/BoardImages/" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].PhotoUrl) "evaluates to then check for ~/BoardImages/" + m[j].PhotoUrl, Then use the base url plus the expression to see if you can see the image on browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your inline css is not in correct format change

```
 <div class="image_div" style="background:@Url.Content("~/BoardImages/" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].PhotoUrl))"></div>
```

to

```
 <div class="image_div" style="background: url(@Url.Content("~/BoardImages/" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].PhotoUrl)))"></div>
```

in css when you apply the background the proper format  is `style="background:url(urlpath)"`

Comment: iam not getting value in  m => m[j].PhotoUrl

Comment: place a breakpoint on var selectResult = db.Boards.ToList(); to check the value in selectResult

Comment: there I am getting all the values from the table . instead of m => m[j].PhotoUrl, other m => m[j].name,etc are getting to the main page

Comment: only the problem with the image loading

Comment: so you are saying that m => m[j].PhotoUrl is returned in list? if so what is the value returned?

Comment: yes, it is coming to the list but not displaying in the page

Comment: I want you to show one value e.g like abc.jpg. the full value i just want to confirm the path